# HAProxy stats page explanation

Tags: haproxy

In the HAProxy stats page under the front end section what does Errors - Req mean?

```
Errors             |
Req   | Conn | Resp
31 758|      |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/management.html#9.1), this value maps to the ereq column in the CSV stats page and means the following:

> 12. ereq [LF..]: request errors. Some of the possible causes are:
>
>     - early termination from the client, before the request has been sent.
>     - read error from the client
>     - client timeout
>     - client closed connection
>     - various bad requests from the client.
>     - request was tarpitted.

Comment: "various bad requests from the client" - Are these HTTP 4xx responses?

Comment: @Ajay I believe some of these can result in various 4xx HTTP responses, for example, on a read timeout, a 408 response is returned by haproxy and this counter is incremented.  However, I don't believe this includes 4xx responses returned by your downstream proxied servers.

Comment: They are not 40X responses. These errors means that the client terminated the connection abruptly or didn't make a valid request, there can't be a response in these conditions and without response there is no concept of status code.

Comment: @user5994461 I see what you’re saying, that this field refers to request errors, and is unrelated to reponses retuned by haproxy.  But the result of some of these errors does cause haproxy to return a 40x response, like in the example I wrote above.

Comment: I think this counter is increased even when user presses the stop button or clicks a link to load another page in their browser while the data transfer is still going.